# Backbone: Error when adding static json file to collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a static json file `myjson.json` that has been validated using JSONLint.

I am trying to use this static json to add data to a collection but I keep getting the same error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Testing/app/scripts/src/myjson.json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am not sure why the `success` in the fetch() is not firing.

My folder structure looks like this

```
->index.html
->app
    ->scripts
        ->src
            ->main.js
            ->myjson.json
        ->views
            ->app.js
        ->models
            ->ModelAndCollection.js
```

Inside ModelAndCollection.js:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {

  var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  });

  var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TheModel,

    url: './app/scripts/src/item-data.json'
  });

  return TheCollection;

});
```

Inside App.js

```
define(['backbone', '../models/ModelAndCollection'], function(Backbone, ModelAndCollection) {

  var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {

      this.collection = new ModelAndCollection();

      console.log('initialize!!!');

      this.collection.fetch({
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log('error');
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return App;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an issue that you are running without a server and you try to AJAX load files from the filesystem.

It will be resolved if you run this app under a web server, the easiest thing to do is to install xampp or one of those if you are on Windows or on Mac/Linux install `nodejs` and `npm install -g http-server` and then just go into the directory where you host your files and in the console write

`http-server`

it will load up a server on port 8080 and you can reach it from localhost:8080

Then everything will work out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize that.  Is there a way to to add the .json file to the collection without an ajax call to a server?  This is my first attempt with a static file.

Comment: you can add it to the page itself with script tabs or to the initializer but your best bet is a webserver.